# O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Olá, bom(a) dia,tarde ou noite, eu gostaria que vocês me ajudassem a responder o que eu estou fazendo de errado no meu código, pois, eu já tentei refazer e fazer de tudo e mais um pouco, e não estou compreendendo, vou explicar por passos:

**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX8dU.png)**
Bom, eu criei um sistema de select de perguntas, mas antes de eu selecionar a pergunta em sí, eu tenho que selecionar o gênero da mesma, pois á no banco, perguntas de atendimento e perguntas de produto.

[image: Print do Select]

[Codigo HTML & PHP do Select]

```
    <div class="card" style="width: 75rem; height: 31rem; margin-top: 1rem; margin-left: 1px;">

    <div class="card-header">
        <h2 align="center">Painel Administrativo - Selecione as Perguntas:</b> </h2>
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">

        <!-- Passa as perguntas via metodo POST mas não as salva no user_tb -->
        <form action="cliente.php" method="POST">

            <h6>Selecione o genero das perguntas: </h6>

            <!-- Script de puxar os generos selecionados -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('#selecionar').change(function(){
                    $('.perguntas').hide();
                    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
                });
            });
            </script>

            <!-- Select com as opções de generos -->
            <select id="selecionar" class="col-sm-12">
                <option value="0">...</option>
                <option value="atendimento">Atendimento</option>
                <option value="produto">Produto</option>
            </select>
            <!-- Opção 1 = Atendimento -->
            <div id="atendimento" class="perguntas" style="display: none;">
                <br><b>Selecione as perguntas:</b></br><br>

                <?php

                // seleciona na tabela perguntas_tb somente o genero de atendimento
                $sqlselecionargenero = "SELECT * FROM perguntas_tb WHERE genero = 'Atendimento' ";

                // prepara o genero de atendimento a ser executado
                $preparargenero = $conn->prepare($sqlselecionargenero);
                $preparargenero -> execute();

                // cria apartir da preparação de puxar os generos do banco de dados, uma variavel chamada pa
                // PA = Pergunta de Atendimento
                // cada pergunta tem que ter seu propio valor para ser atribuido a ela 5 checkbox
                // how to do?

                foreach ($preparargenero as $pa) {
                    $id = $pa["id"];
                    $perguntas = $pa["perguntas"];

                    echo "<p><input type='checkbox' name='atendimento[]' value='$perguntas' id='' name='atendimento' >"." ".$perguntas;

                }

                ?>

                <p><button type="submit">Salvar perguntas</button></p>
            </div>

            <!-- Opção 2 = Produto -->
            <div id="produto" class="perguntas" style="display: none;">
                <!-- AINDA FALTA FAZER A PARTE DE PRODUTO, ESTOU PRIMEIRO FAZENDO A PARTE DE ATENDIMENTO -->
            </div>

        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

Ele gera apartir da quantidade de perguntas com genero de Atendimento no banco, ou seja ele puxa todas as perguntas, até ai tudo bem...

**[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Oba.png)** Após eu selecionar o gênero, e escolher as perguntas e clickar em salvar
eu passo via metodo post, as perguntas que eu selecionei para uma pagina cliente.php, e essa pagina seria como se fosse um formulário, onde apartir das perguntas que eu passei eu atribuo 5 checkbox's exclusivos para cada pergunta, e apartir desses checkbox's eu gostaria de atribuir valores a eles, e enviar tais valores ao banco de dados para que eu pudesse criar um gráfico. Mas ai é que eu não consigo desenvolver nada a mais, como eu separo as perguntas por paginação?
não gostaria que todas ficassem todas em uma mesma pagina, por exemplo, eu gostaria de usar um recurso do bootstrap de avançar e voltar, para responder as perguntas, e não responder todas em uma só div, alguém poderia me ajudar?

[image: Print do Resultado do Select]

```
    <div style="margin-left: 1rem; margin-top: 1rem;">

    <form method="POST">


        <?php

        // Verifica se alguma pergunta foi selecionada

        if(isset($_POST["atendimento"])) {

            // Faz um loop no Array de checkbox

            // A função count retorna a quantidade de checkbox selecionado

            for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["atendimento"]); $i++) {


                echo $_POST['atendimento'][$i]."<br />";
                echo "<p>";
                echo "<input type='radio' name='$i'> Muito Satisfeito ";
                echo "<input type='radio' name='$i'> Satisfeito ";
                echo "<input type='radio' name='$i'> Pouco Satisfeito ";
                echo "<input type='radio' name='$i'> Insatisfeito ";
                echo "<input type='radio' name='$i'> Muito Insatisfeito ";
                echo "<p><br>";

            }
        }
        ?>

        <p><button type='submit'>Enviar</button></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Ficaria grato em que puder me ajudar!!

Comment: ```echo "<input type='radio' name='$i'> Muito Satisfeito ";``` quando fazes isso porque não adicionas um campo de ```value="XXX"```

Comment: Sim, é o que já fiz, pra atribuir valor, só como cada pergunta, tem que ter uma resposta diferente, os valores vão ficar duplicados de cb em cima e em baixo, ou seja, na hora de for fazer o gráfico, não vai ter como separar oq é oq

Comment: Em cada uma metes value="Muito Satisfeito" ou value="Satisfeito" cada um fica com um valor diferente dependendo do radio check que o utilizador deu.

Answer (score -3):

venho aqui resolver seu problema, que fique claro que estou usando o xampp com o php 7.4, vamos resolver na ordem mas simples e fácil perguntas.

1. Paginação no PHP

Para paginar no php você deve usar o comando **Paginate**, para passar a página você precisa de uma url dinâmica que acompanhe a paginação, veja o exemplo abaixo.

```
$suaPergunta->paginate(2)
```

Nesse exemplo a variavel $suaPergunta é uma colletion que contem as perguntas do banco de dados através de um **GET**.
paginate é o método usado para paginação, e o número dois é a quantidade de itens por paginação, nesse caso se for 10 perguntas ele vai exibir de 2 em 2 perguntas pois foi o parâmetro passado no método, nesse caso seria 5 páginas com 2 perguntas.

Para passar para a próxima página você deve usar algo parecido com isso:

```
$suaPergunta->links()
```

Assim ele irá gerar os números com a paginação para que possa clicar e ir de uma paginação para outra, você deve chamar sua colletion e em seguida a função do PHP links() que ele irá montar em seu rodapé os links.
Se você usar um frameWork como laravel verá o quão simples é isso.

2. Salvar respostas no banco

Tudo nesse caso é questão do seu HTML, é necessário que cada item desse, no caso suas checkbox tenham nome unicos e id, você deve nomear cada checkbox de acordo com o id da pergunta para gerar um array com dados unicos.

Você precisa criar um loop que seja obtido a informação da pergunda supondo que o array com sua pergunta é $suaPergunta e ele possui ID, vamos usar foreach.

Você também precisaria que as respostas estivessem no banco de dados, assim ficaria as informações mais dinâmicas, sendo assim também usaremos foreach nas respostas.

```
    <div style="margin-left: 1rem; margin-top: 1rem;">

    <form method="POST">
     

        <?php

        foreach($suaPergunta as $pergunta){

        // Verifica se alguma pergunta foi selecionada

        if(isset($_POST["atendimento"])) {

            // Faz um loop no Array de checkbox

            // A função count retorna a quantidade de checkbox selecionado

            foreach($suaResposta as $key => $resposta) {


                echo $_POST['atendimento'][$key]."<br />";
                echo "<p>";
                echo "<input type='radio' name='pergunta.$pergunta->id._.$resposta->id'> $resposta->descricao";                
                echo "<p><br>";

            }
        }
     }
        ?>

        <p><button type='submit'>Enviar</button></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

$key é a contagem do foreach, foreach por si só já é um for porém mais trabalhado, ou seja, muito mais fácil de percorrer os dados do array.

Dessa forma assim que você der o post saberá qual pergunta for respondida e com qual resposta, assim poderá salvar no banco facilmente.

Veja a referência de como trabalhar com arrays e foreach:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php